# ffmpeg makes video with no sound on video.js

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, fluent-ffmpeg

I have this code that creates m3u8 file to stream a mkv file after transcoding.

```
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
childProcess = ffmpeg()
    .input(inputFilePath)
    // .native()
    .inputOptions(['-y', '-progress', 'pipe:1'])
    .outputOptions(['-b:v 1M', '-hls_time 2', '-hls_list_size 0', '-hls_segment_size 500000'])
    .output('public/output.m3u8')
    .on('end', () => {
        io.emit('conversionComplete', { percent: 100, time: totalDuration, totalDuration, timemark: millisecondsToTimeString(totalDuration) });
        childProcess = null
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
        io.emit('conversionError', { error });
        childProcess = null
    })
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
        io.emit('conversionProgress', { ...progress, time: timeStringToMilliseconds(progress.timemark), totalDuration });
    });

childProcess.run();
```

The m3u8 is readable by VLC Player and video.js and can be casted to Chrome Cast. For some others, 4Go files moreless, it works only when the video is transcoded without sound with option .inputOption('-an').

Here's the content of m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:4
#EXTINF:10.000000,
output4.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
output5.ts
#EXTINF:8.640000,
output6.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
output7.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
output8.ts
```

- I tried with all possible audio codecs provided by ffmpeg
- I tried with bigger/smaller parts for ts files
- I tried with other bitrate

Thanks in advance for your ideas